# How to Resize the In-App-Browser in Ionic

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native, inappbrowser

I’m trying to use the in-app-browser plugin in my application. But while using the plugin, it covers the whole screen. The application has a header and a footer, I need to have the browser in between them.
Please let me know, if this is possible.
Thank you!!

Comment: How to use "useWideViewPort" in ionic's in-app-browser. Can it resize the browser according to our needs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use iframe tag for your requirement here is a demo for use

```
<ion-content>

<h1>The iframe element</h1>

<iframe src="https://Your site URL" title="Your site URL">
</iframe>

</ion-content>
```

OR you can use this plugin if you don't want to go with iFrame

```
cordova plugin add com.lesfrancschatons.cordova.plugins.overappbrowser
```

for plugin documentation [click here](https://github.com/etabard/Cordova-OverAppBrowser)

Comment: Hi Bhavesh,
iFrame is currently being used in the application. But we need to use the in-app-browser. Is there any chance we can use the in-app-browser and link it to some tag and then apply customization.

Comment: in-app-browser open it's own window that is not resizable but another plugin is used for achieve your requirement you can set height and width. [use this plugin](https://github.com/etabard/Cordova-OverAppBrowser) 

here is a plugin 
cordova plugin add com.lesfrancschatons.cordova.plugins.overappbrowser

Comment: Can this be used with capacitor. I'm using capacitor.

Comment: it won't be used with capacitor right now

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the guidance. I'll see if there are any other alternatives